# Can I use mongock with Spring Data Repositories?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I tried to inject with `@Autowired` annotation a repository into changelog 
and it doesn't get injected.

Config uses spring application context

```
@Bean
public SpringBootMongock mongock(ApplicationContext springContext, MongoClient mongoClient) {
  return new SpringBootMongockBuilder(mongoClient, "yourDbName", "com.package.to.be.scanned.for.changesets")
      .setApplicationContext(springContext) 
      .setLockQuickConfig()
      .build();
}
```

And the changelog

```
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class MyMigration {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repo;

    @ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "someChangeId", author = "testAuthor")
    public void importantWorkToDo(DB db){
       repo.findAll() // here null pointer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, notice that if you are using repositories in your changelogs, it's a bad practice to use it for writes, as it won't be covered by the lock mechanism(this is feature is coming soon), only for reads.

To inject your repository(or any other dependency) you simply need to inject it in your changeSet method signature, like this:

```
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class MyMigration {


    @ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "someChangeId", author = "testAuthor")
    public void importantWorkToDo(MongoTemplate template, MyRepository repo){
       repo.findAll(); this should work
    }
}
```

Notice that you should use the last version(at this moment 3.2.4)  and DB class is not supported anymore. Please use MongoDatabase or MongoTemplate(preferred).

[Documentation to Mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock#injecting-custom-dependencies-to-change-logs)

Answer (score 1):

we have recently released the version 4.0.7.alpha, which among other things allows you to use Spring repositories(and any other custom bean you wish) in your changeSets with no problem. You can insert, update, delete and read. It will be safely covered by the lock.

The only restriction is that it needs to be an interface, which should be the common case for Spring repositories.

Please take a look to this [example](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock-integration-tests/tree/master/mongock-spring-v5/mongock-spring5-springdata3-it)